# Mean and Covariance of Office Hours

Tags: self-study, mean, covariance

I have a homework assignment with the following question. I've attempted to solve the problems and my answers are below, but I feel like they are incorrect, and have no idea how to check. I would be very grateful for any help you can provide:

```
Posted office hours notwithstanding, students make calls at the offices of their 
professors and have formed the impression that professors are more likely to be away
from their offices on Friday than any other working day. A review of calls, 
1/5 of which are on Fridays, indicates that for 16% of Friday calls, the professor 
is away from his or her office, while this occurs for only 12% of calls on every 
other working day.  Define two random variables as follows:

X = 1 if call is made on a Friday; otherwise, X = 0

Y = 1 if professor is away from his or her office; otherwise, Y = 0


a.  Find the mean value of X, namely, E(X).

b.  Find the mean value of Y, namely, E(Y).

c.  Find (to four decimal places) and interpret the covariance between X and Y.
```

---

My Answers:

`A` : 0.2(1) = **0.2**

`B` : (0.12)0.2 + (0.12)0.2 +(0.12)0.2 +(0.12)0.2 +(0.16)0.2  = **0.128**

`C` : E(xy) – E(x)*E(y) :

Comment: How did you arrive at 0.2 in A and why are you multiplying by 1? Why are you multiplying the values in B by 0.2?

Comment: I was using 0.2 (or 1/5) as the probability of calls on a given Friday. Am I incorrect to assume this?

Comment: The 0.2 wouldn't be an assumption, it's a calculation and correctly 1/5, the probability of a call on Friday. But your comment doesn't answer either of the questions.

Comment: Suggesting that for Mon-Thurs, the value of X is 0, I shortened : 0.2(0) + 0.2(0) + 0.2(0) + 0.2(0) + 0.2(1) to  0.2(1). And for B, I was using this same equation, using Y as the probability that a teacher receives a call, and 0.2 as the p(y) for each day.

Comment: (c) asks for a numeric covariance. So you need to give a number.   What does $XY$ mean? What's $E(XY)$?

Comment: E(xy) would be the expected mean for x and y. And XY is part of the equation I found inline to calculate the covariance.